# java Convert Hex NCRs texts to unicode characters

Tags: java, android, unicode, hex

I'm making a feed reader app for local languages. A news site provide rss feed with these characters

`&#x0D39;&#x0D32;&#x0D47;&#x0D3E; &#x0D38;&#x0D4D;&#x0D31;&#x0D4D;&#x0D31;&#x0D3E;&#x0D15;&#x0D4D;&#x0D15;&#x0D4D;&#x0D13;&#x0D35;&#x0D7C; &#x0D2B;&#x0D4D;&#x0D32;&#x0D47;&#x0D3E;`

Which actually means 
`ഹലോ സ്റ്റാക്ക്ഓവർ ഫ്ലോ`
this is also what I want display in my app..

How can I convert this input to the required form..

Comment: you have to find such font that convert english to local language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
String input = "&#x0D39;&#x0D32;&#x0D47;&#x0D3E; &#x0D38;&#x0D4D;&#x0D31;"
    + "&#x0D4D;&#x0D31;&#x0D3E;&#x0D15;&#x0D4D;&#x0D15;&#x0D4D;&#x0D13;"
    + "&#x0D35;&#x0D7C; &#x0D2B;&#x0D4D;&#x0D32;&#x0D47;&#x0D3E;";
Pattern HEX = Pattern.compile("(?i)&#x([0-9a-f]+);|&#(\\d+);");
Matcher m = HEX.matcher(input);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(sb,
        String.valueOf((char) (m.group(1) != null ?
            Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16) :
            Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)))));
m.appendTail(sb);
String output = sb.toString();
System.out.println(output);
// -> ഹലോ സ്റ്റാക്ക്ഓവർ ഫ്ലോ
```

This code can handle also decimal NCR.
But cannot handle `x10000` to `x10FFFF`.

Or you can use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) like this.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
String output = doc.text();
System.out.println(output);
// -> ഹലോ സ്റ്റാക്ക്ഓവർ ഫ്ലോ
```

Comment: Any equivalent solutions in python?